# Hubble HST scheduling algorithm

Tags: telescope, hubble-telescope, nasa, algorithm

NASA developed SPIKE: Intelligent Scheduling of Hubble Space Telescope Observations [(HST)](http://comanche.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/spike/documents/spike-chapter3.pdf) and [this](http://www.stsci.edu/~miller/papers-and-meetings/93-Intelligent-Scheduling/spike/spike-chapter3.html).

My question is simple, is there a programming library, preferably in python or C#, to implement the algorithm? AFAIK  NASA never released their code.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you wanting to schedule an observation or to apply the algorithm to some other end? Or just curious of the implementation?

Comment: @MitchGoshorn I want to apply the algorithm in my software, and willing to pay for it if it's not free and if the price is reasonable, i'm a python guy but the boys working on the project, prefer C#, any of them will do, even java - and I want to schedule tasks too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is apparently an option on the STSI (Space Telescope Science Institure) website to [try their Spike implementation](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/spike/try).

This doesn't clearly answer your question, as it's not open, and I don't know the language that has been used.

However, there is a lot of information in the documents you provided and on the linked website, so maybe you can start your own implementation of the algorithm? I'd be happy to help!

Comment: i contacted them before asking this question, never received a reply

Comment: Oh... OK then. Please ignore my answer then! Shall we try and do it ourselves?

Comment: yes it's the only option :)

Comment: Please do chime in if you need/want help! We can setup a github account if you want.

Comment: yes why not, my github account is elieobeid7 and i have private repo if you want, i have been accepted by github and i was given this bundle :D http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/My-Acer-Aspire-V3-571G-6622-wont-recognize-my-NVIDIA-GeForce-GT/td-p/111827 lets try to do it for fun :)

Comment: my email is  elieobeid7@gmail.com